# Why doesn't PHP increment array index properly?

Tags: php, arrays

Let's say I have this array:

```
array(12) {
  [0] =>
  array(0) {
  }
  // [...]
  [9] =>
  string(5) "test"
  [10] =>
  array(0) {
  }
  [11] =>
  class stdClass#5 (0) {
  }
}
```

All items in this array where added like this `$a[] = $somevalue`.

Now I add another item: `$a[] = new Foobar('bar');`

However this results in:

```
array(13) {
  [0] =>
  array(0) {
  }
  // [...]
  [9] =>
  string(5) "test"
  [10] =>
  array(0) {
  }
  [11] =>
  class stdClass#5 (0) {
  }
  [21] =>
  class Foobar#8 (3) {
    protected $id =>
    string(11) "bar"
  }
}
```

My `Foobar` object is not `$a[12]`, why? Is there anything I can do such that PHP iterates properly?

**Update**:
I was not able to reproduce this behaviour in a single file. Unfortunately, a whole framework is involved in my code. As I'm only in control of the last statement (`$a[] = new Foobar('id');`), can I do something before that expression to force PHP to iterate properly?

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://codepad.org/0cRWVEMC). Are you sure you're not [setting & unsetting](http://codepad.org/JoQX9py1) 12-20?

Comment: Please show us your full code!

Comment: @kingkero The items might be set & unset, is there any way I can reset the counter?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you mean this, but here it goes: PHP arrays do not have to be indexed in the standard way; If you unset `12-20`, the last item (namely `21` will not have its index changed). You can also have strings as keys; it's more like a key-value pair than a standard table you might find in other languages. You can use `foreach` to iterate over an array.

```
$a = array(
  0 => 2,
  21 => 30,
  "foo" => "bar"
);

foreach ($a as $val)
{
    echo $val;
    echo "\n";
}
```

will print:

```
2
30
bar
```